# Explanation/intuition on a (entry level) mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I have a question about the following problem (from this script: http://www.phys.hawaii.edu/~morse/P170Fa15-11.pdf)
[image: mechanics problem: picture hanging on two ropes with different angles]

I understand the calculations but I just don't understand why the sum of T1 and T2 is greater than the weight.
I guess if the ropes would be at 90 degrees (hanging straight down from the ceiling) the sum of the forces would be equal to the weight and if the angles of the ropes go closer to zero the sum of the forces will increase.

But what, from a physical point of view, causes this additional force?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot add two vectors (numerically) that are not parallel. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **vector** sum of $\mathbf{T}_1$ and $\mathbf{T}_2$ is equal to the weight; that has to happen if the picture is in equilibrium. But they are vectors that point in different directions, so the magnitude of $\mathbf{T}_1 + \mathbf{T}_2$ is not equal to the sum of the magnitudes.

What you need to sum are the vertical components of the forces, just like equation $y$ says. The sum is equal to the weight, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all forget about forces and tension etc, basically you can think triangle inequality and you can check it in Wikipedia 
( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality )so
It should be...

Comment: What's that again?